# R `parse()` for subscripts mixed numbers and letters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display subscripts in ggplot facet labels where there are mixed letters and numbers in the subscript using `parse()`.

This works:

```
>parse(text="cI[933]")
```

And so does this:

```
>parse(text="cI[W]")
```

But not these:

```
>parse(text="cI[933W]")
Error in parse(text = "cI[933W]") : <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: cI[933W
          ^

> parse(text="cI[9W33]")
Error in parse(text = "cI[9W33]") : <text>:1:5: unexpected symbol
1: cI[9W33
        ^
```

For an example in [ggplot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/label_parsed.html):

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl2 <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels = c("cI[123]", "cI[ABC]", "cI[456]"))
qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars) + facet_grid(. ~ cyl2, labeller = label_parsed)
```

That works fine, but:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl2 <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels = c("cI[AB3]", "cI[2CD]", "cI[EF1]"))
qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars) + facet_grid(. ~ cyl2, labeller = label_parsed)
```

...does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is failing because `2CD` is not a legal symbol according to the R parser (symbols must begin with an alphabetic character and must contain only alphanumeric + `[._]` characters (I think)). As a quick workaround, you can protect the illegal symbols with single quotes:

```
mtcars$cyl2 <- factor(mtcars$cyl, 
    labels = c("cI[AB3]", "cI['2CD']", "cI[EF1]"))
```

The quotation marks don't show up in the plot labels.

From the [introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf):

> Normally all alphanumeric symbols are allowed (and in some countries this includes accented letters) plus ‘.’ and ‘_’, with the restriction that a name must start with ‘.’ or a letter, and if it starts with ‘.’ the second character must not be a digit.